# htaccess - want to redirect my.example.com to example.com/my

Tags: .htaccess

i want to redirect my.example.com to example.com/my . I am using drupal . in this website(http://www.easymodrewrite.com/example-subdomains) , i found these steps

1. in dns,point *.domain.com to my ip - **DONE**
2. in server httpd.conf , ServerAlias www.domain.com domain.com to ServerAlias www.domain.com domain.com *.domain.com - **Not done ,as i am on shared server**
3. in .htaccess , add following

> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>    Options +FollowSymLinks
>    Options +Indexes
>    RewriteEngine On
>    RewriteBase /
>    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.domain.com$ [NC]
>    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).domain.com [NC]
>    RewriteRule (.*) %2/$1 [L]
> </IfModule>
> ```

its not working .. is it important to edit httpd.conf or am i mssing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> its not working .. is it important to edit httpd.conf or am i mssing something?

Yes, otherwise the webserver won't know to accept requests for hosts other than what the server is set to. There may be some setting in cpanel or whatever your host uses to configure the server that allows you to set the server host to *.domain.com

Otherwise, the rewrite rules should be fine, but there won't be any redirecting, just internal rewrite. If you want it to redirect, change the rule line to:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/%2/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: i tried this manual rule

`RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/bbb [L,R]`

and it is working fine

Comment: but the previous code is not working! you think still its is related to httpd.conf?

Comment: Yes, because this condition will never be met if the server doesn't know to accept these hosts: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).domain.com [NC]`

Comment: i have checked if the condition working.. and found its working .. also changed code 
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/%1 [L]`

i dont want redirect so i didnt used R .. now redirection working fine, but i want only internal redirect!

Comment: removed new code is `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1 [L]`  but now its giving internal server error .. tried this too `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1 [L]`